# Disable Jquery parallax on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, parallax

i'm really sorry I know there are many similar topics for the same question. except that i'm confused because as i noticed there is no universal code for disabling functions. i think with JS is complicated (i have no clue ). but here is the situation. i found a jquery code somewhere on the internet, i wanted to use it through elementor with wordpress to make the background images scroll too ( parallax )
everything worked perfectly. the only problem is with mobile devices, the effect is corrupt and looks awful, and i want to disable it. here is the code:

```
    function jquery_parallax() {

   ?>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">


;(function($) {

   'use strict'

    var testMobile;
    var isMobile = {
        Android: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
        },
        BlackBerry: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
        },
        iOS: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
        },
        Opera: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
        },
        Windows: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
        },
        any: function() {
            return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
        }
    };

    var parallax = function() {
        testMobile = isMobile.any();
        if (testMobile == null) {
            $(".parallax").parallax("50%", 0.3);
        }
    };



    // Dom Ready
    $(function() {
        parallax();
    });
})(jQuery);

/*
jQuery Parallax 1.1.3
Author: Ian Lunn
Plugin URL: http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/

Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
*/
!function(n){var t=n(window),e=t.height();t.resize(function(){e=t.height()}),n.fn.parallax=function(o,r,i){function u(){var i=t.scrollTop();l.each(function(t,u){var l=n(u),f=l.offset().top,s=a(l);i>f+s||f>i+e||l.css("backgroundPosition",o+" "+Math.round((l.data("firstTop")-i)*r)+"px")})}var a,l=n(this);l.each(function(t,e){$element=n(e),$element.data("firstTop",$element.offset().top)}),a=i?function(n){return n.outerHeight(!0)}:function(n){return n.height()},(arguments.length<1||null===o)&&(o="50%"),(arguments.length<2||null===r)&&(r=.1),(arguments.length<3||null===i)&&(i=!0),t.bind("scroll",u).resize(u),u()}}(jQuery);

    </script>
    <?php

}


if (!(is_admin())) {
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
add_action('wp_head', 'jquery_parallax');
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!testMobile) {
        $(".parallax").parallax("50%", 0.3);
}
```

You dont need to check against null, you want to check if its not (!) true.

By the way "disabling a function seems very complicated" :

```
yourfunctiontodisable=()=>console.log("disabled function called");
```

Comment: Actually, his test function does return `null`.  It *should* return only true/false.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply.
I have tried to replace null by "false" and "true", the reslut is the parallax now is disabled everywhere. I only want to disable it on mobile devices.

thank you again sir!

Answer (score 0):

Simply edit your mobile device width. Now parallax only working on more than 991px devices.

```
if (window_width > 991) {
    $(".parallax").parallax("50%", 0.3);
});
```